# how to get a class with forName() in a different package?

Tags: java, class, package

Alright, consider the following example:

```
inside of the src/ folder, i have the following packages :

org/

com/
```

Class Foo is located in org.somepackage;

Class Doo is located in com.apackage;

**Foo** needs to access **Doo** using *Class.forName();*

if i try using Class.forName("com.apackage.Doo");

i get ClassNotFoundException as they are in different Packages.

how can **Foo** acess **Doo** in this hiearchy?

---

### EDIT

Here is some more background:

the complete asked about info :
[image]

this is my batch file, jar file, and the src file that has the file im trying to access.

this is the class in the src file :

[image]

this is my batch file :
[image]

now when i try to access the file Doo, this is the error:

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean class `Doo` is located in package `com.apackage`? Surely its package doesn't *also* include `Doo`. But if the full class name is `com.apackage.Doo` then `Class.forName` should be fine - my guess is that your classpath is wrong.

Comment: @JonSkeet dumb mistake, you're right it's org.somepackage, however the problem still stands, i just phrased it wrong. fixed

Comment: Right. So I can assure you that `Class.forName` *does* work across packages... so my guess is that the classloader isn't aware of `Doo`. How are you running this code? Can you give a short but complete example of how you're building and running it?

Comment: Foo and all it's package under org/ is actually placed in a JAR file. the jar file is in the main directory. And then in the source folder is the com/ package that has Doo. here's an image as an example : http://puu.sh/c0INs/9a1c6f6776.png

Comment: Looks like most likely issue is the class is not findable by the class loader.  my best guess is the classpath does not include the jar with the needed class or the directory that is the base directory for the class.

Comment: What have you specified in your classpath?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis which one?

Comment: @Shed Your java program's, at runtime.

Comment: nothing, it's just java -jar MyJar.jar

Comment: @JonSkeet just one more time, are you sure a JAR file is allowed to load a class outside of it's package? like this jar i made has a package org.package.Class and this class is trying to access a class outside of this jar and in a different folder

Comment: @Shed: It's not the jar file. It's the classloader. If the classloader is able to access the class, the package doesn't matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet the Class.forName()'s parms aren't supposed to be for the same package? does it look everywhere?

Comment: @Shed: No, it's the fully-qualified classname. Look at the example in the documentation: `Class.forName("java.lang.Thread")`. Try that from your code, which isn't in the `java.lang` package. It'll still work. It looks everywhere the classloader knows about.

Comment: @JonSkeet you said it 'knows' about, so does it know my org.package.Foo? if not, how can i let it "know" it? (sorry for this long question, i'm still learning)

Comment: Without knowing exactly how you're running things, whether you've got the jar file in your classpath etc, we can't possible help - and SO comments aren't meant to end up as a discussion like this. Please edit your question to indicate *exactly* how you're running this, and maybe someone will answer... I'm going to bed.

Comment: @JonSkeet i added all info needed for you i think, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
java -cp src -jar FooJar.jar
```

From the [`java` tool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI):

> When you use the -jar option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored.

Try running it as:

```
java - cp src;FooJar.jar foo.Whatever
```

(where `foo.Whatever` is the fully-qualified name of the class containing your `main` method).

Comment: the main method of the classes im trying to acess? because the jar file contains one as well?

Comment: @Shed: The main method in the class you're trying to run - which would be the one in the jar file. The entry point you want the JVM to start.

Comment: oh the jar goes automatically to my main class when i click it as i have specified it in a manifest file. I'm trying to access a class outside of the jar

Comment: @Shed: Yes, but that's where the documentation I've quoted is relevant - if you use that bootstrap mechanism, other classpath options are ignored. You could create your own `ClassLoader` within the app, of course... but that would probably be more work. Hopefully it's reasonably clear now - if you need more advice, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: i have finally figured it out, thanks a lot for being so patient with me.